# win-KeX((Kali Desktop Experience for Windows) external monitor scaling

Tags: kali-linux, wsl2, tigervnc

I installed win-KeX recently under wsl2. however, I am using multiple monitors to do my works and the scaling of the screens for the external monitors is not scaling to the right size. As you can see in image 2, when I go on full screen with chrome the top par of the page where the bookmark and URL entry box resides is cut off and inaccessible. any idea how it could be fixed.
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r7Wg.jpg)  [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNOmb.png) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKspe.png) [image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uipG.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I figured the problem guys. it was because of windows display scaling setting. The scaling was set to 125% on windows, so kex was using that scaling hence resulting in a cut off screen even though it does not happen on windows side. so the point is the scaling for the display has to be 100% if you are using external monitor.